# Axios API call throwing a 'JSON param empty error'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, axios

I'm building an API call with Axios in TypeScript, the API requires the calls to be made in json format while specifying JSON-RPC version and method. The API provider shared a postman example demonstrating how the request body should be formatted:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:3000/api/get-products' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "call",
    "params": {
        "db_name": "mig_api",
        "user": "test@api.com",
        "password": "Test123!",
        "LanguageCode": "en_EN"
    }
}'
```

However, my goal is to send all the necessary data through the Axios call and receive the response by accessing the URL directly. The problem I'm facing is that every time I make the call, I consistently receive the same error from the server:

```
{ jsonrpc: '2.0', id: null, result: 'JSON param empty error' }
```

Here is the code for the API call:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { ConstDataSet } from '../../core/constants/data-set.coonstant';

export class DataService {

    private apiUrl: string = 'https://api.provider.com/products/get_json';

    async fetchData(constDataSet: typeof ConstDataSet): Promise<AxiosResponse | void> {

        return await axios.post(this.apiUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                jsonrpc: "2.0",
                method: "call",
            },
            params: {
                username: constDataSet.user,
                password: constDataSet.password,
                db_name: constDataSet.db_name,
                LanguageCode: constDataSet.LanguageCode
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}

export default new DataService();
```

The constDataSet is obtaining values from an exported constant with assigned environment variables. I know the .env is working properly because I'm using it to connect a database and the app PORT and they are working fine:

```
import { DataSet } from "../interfaces/data-set.interface";

export const ConstDataSet: DataSet =  {
    db_name: process.env.API_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.API_USER,
    password: process.env.API_PASSWORD,
    LanguageCode: process.env.API_LANGUAGE_CODE
} as const
```

Even if I try to hardcode the data directly in the axios call, the same error happens. I've attempted different approaches to send the required data, such as:

```
return await axios.post(this.apiUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                jsonrpc: "2.0",
                method: "call",
                username: constDataSet.user,
                password: constDataSet.password,
                db_name: constDataSet.db_name,
                LanguageCode: constDataSet.LanguageCode
            },
```

Also tried to send all the data in the params section, deleting the headers, sending the headers as data or params, adding the json rpc as a parm for the axios.post like this:

```
const body = {
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "call",
        }
return await axios.post(this.apiUrl, body {
```

Unfortunately, none of these changes have resolved the issue, and I'm consistently encountering the same error. I'm seeking suggestions to troubleshoot and overcome this error. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try making `params` part of the JSON object, and as axios.post takes these parameters:

```
axios.post(url, data, config)
```

swap data and headers.

Try this:

```
   return await axios.post(this.apiUrl, {
       jsonrpc: "2.0",
       method: "call",
       params: {
           username: constDataSet.user,
           password: constDataSet.password,
           db_name: constDataSet.db_name,
           LanguageCode: constDataSet.LanguageCode
       }
   }, {
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
   }).then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
   }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Also, you might change your `DataSet` interface to something like this:

```
interface DataSet {
  jsonrpc: '2.0';
  method: 'call';
  params: {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    db_name: string;
    LanguageCode: string;
  };
}
```

or maybe create combined types:

```
interface ConstDataSet {
  params: {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    db_name: string;
    LanguageCode: string;
  };
}

interface JsonRpc {
  jsonrpc: '2.0';
  method: 'call';
}

type Payload = JsonRpc & ConstDataSet;

//...

let payload: Payload = {
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  method: 'call',
  params: {
    username: constDataSet.user,
    password: constDataSet.password,
    db_name: constDataSet.db_name,
    LanguageCode: constDataSet.LanguageCode
  }
};
```